# Checking if a String is equal to any given set of strings

Tags: java, string

There are two ways  of checking if the incoming request if of type `PUB` or `PRIV`.

### First

```
private static final String PRIV = "PRIV";
private static final String PUB = "PUB";
...
String request = ...;
if(PRIV.equals(request) || PUB.equals(request)) {
     ...
}
```

### Second

```
private static final String PRIV = "PRIV";
private static final String PUB = "PUB";
...
String request = ...;
if(Arrays.asList(PRIV, PUB).contains(request)) {
    ...
}
```

I like the second way more than the first way.

What are the ***performance gains/downs*** for the *second case*?

### Update

Guess I wasn't able to frame my question properly.

I just want to know if the *traditional* approach

```
if(PRIV.equals(request) || PUB.equals(request) || ...){
    ...
}
```

is anyway *better/worse* than

```
private static final List<String> VALUES = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(PRIV, PUB));
if(VALUES.contains(request)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: First one is faster, also in the first example you should use the reverse order  `PRIV.equals(request)`.

Comment: That was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: In the second case you create a `List` object every time you do the `if`check. It might be better to create an unmodifiable `static final List<String>` beforehand and check against that.

Comment: Such a trivial piece of code is never going to cause performance problems. It would be more logical to use a Set rather than a List though, and to create it once and for all, instead of creating a new one every time the code is executed.

Comment: FWIW, if you have more cases to check, it might be more efficient to use a pre-built `Set` (not a `List`)

Comment: @VPK How much faster? Percent wise. Before concluding on performance you need to get concrete results of an analysis. I can suggest to use JMH to run benchmarks. http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: @Boris, agree, I was considering the time for creating the fixed sized list backed by the array against the already created static final variables.

Comment: How many strings are in your list? (You show just two here, but I presume that's just for brevity of the question.)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Around 50. That's correct.

Comment: With as many as 50 strings, I think Michael Gantman's answer is worth considering. Just do `private static final List<String> VALUES = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(PRIV, PUB));` or, in Java 9, `private static final List<String> VALUES = Set.of(PRIV, PUB);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your 1st option is that it is (or will be) very verbose.

The problem with your 2nd option is that you are creating the list for each request.

There is a 3rd option where in you can create the list ONLY ONCE and make it as  `static` `unmodifiableList` as shown below and then check for the value present inside the list or not:

```
    private static final String PRIV = "PRIV";
    private static final String PUB = "PUB";

    private static final List<String> values = 
           Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{PRIV,PUB})); 

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        if(values.contains(request)) {
            //do something here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively `private static final List<String> values = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{PRIV,PUB}));`

Comment: I agree, which is more concise

Comment: I say also use Set instead of List as the performance of contains() method in Set is O(1) as opposed to List O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve better performance by creating a `Set<String>` instead of `List<String>` with List your performance is O(n) with Set it is O(1). So create a final static unmodifyable set of Strings in a static initializer of your class and then use `set.contains(request)` that would give you the best perfomance - better then with `List`. However if your number of Strings is small then the performance gain is negligeble.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you are doing a leaner search so time complexity is O(N). So theoretically both are same.

But in the first case, you are directly compare string with other string without any extra overload. But in the second case `Arrays.asList(PRIV, PUB)` it will create `ArrayList` so need more memory and more CPU power. and Also `ArrayList.contain` search item in a linear pattern O(N).

finally in first case need `O(N) time` and in second case `O(N) + extra time and memory to create ArrayList`. So the `first case is absolutely good for performance`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Java Microbenchmark Harness](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) (JMH) benchmark results:

**String request = "abc";**

```
Benchmark               Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testFirst   avgt   25   9.408 ±  4.797  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testSecond  avgt   25  40.871 ± 14.343  ns/op
```

**String request = "PRIV";**

```
Benchmark               Mode  Cnt      Score       Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testFirst   avgt   25  39941.986 ± 10612.569  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testSecond  avgt   25  41034.244 ± 12146.154  ns/op
```

As you can see the second case is **approximately 4 times slower** than the first one when the *request* value is not present in the set.

When the *request* value is present in the set, then the performance of both cases is **approximately the same**.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **First method** `string.equals(String object)`, it runs in Time Complexity range of **O(1)** when there is a:

1. Match found,
2. Length different, hence not equal.

Or **O(n)** when the method has to traverse each character to check if they are equal or not.

But when you are using `List.contains(String object)` method, two things are done:

1. Pick each element at a time till a match is found.
2. Internally execute `equals()` method to check it's equality with the input, which again takes time as described for First method.

Refer: [Oracle Docs: List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Hence to conclude, when using `string.equals(String obj)` method, we are directly doing an equality check but when using `List.contains(String object)` method, we are going through one additional step.

This shows why *First method* is faster.

Answer (score -3):

Its very simple to know.

Please execute below class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringTest {
private static final String PRIV = "PRIV";
private static final String PUB = "PUB";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    String request = "PRIV";
    if (request.equals(PRIV) || request.equals(PUB)) {
        System.out.println("----");
    }
    long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);



    long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    String request1 = "PRIV";
    if (Arrays.asList(PRIV, PUB).contains(request1)) {
        System.out.println("----");
    }
    long stopTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(stopTime1 - startTime1);
}
}
```

### Output:

### 203100

224100

**Execution of string comparison is faster that array. The values in each execution may vary but string execution value will be lower**